# problem installing ubuntu 15.10

Tags: system-installation

I tried using a DVD to install ubuntu 15.10 64bit but it stopped / hanged after I chose install ubuntu (instead of try ubuntu). The pc has a CPU that supports 64bit and 4 gb ram.
I tried install it through a bootable usb key, but it stopped at the first shown menu of choices after I chose install ubuntu.
I tried many times. Same problem.
What could be the reason? 
Should I try 32bit older ubuntu?
Thanks for help.

Comment: If your pc is 64 built don't have to install 32bit version. Can you make sure that you didn't broke the ISO at the first place?

Comment: How can I make sure that the ISO isn't broken?

Comment: You have to download it again, if this freeze happens in both CD and USB you might have already checked it by booting :p Download the ISO again, you can try torrent download as well it's usually faster than official servers.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. I will inform the result asap. :D Maybe this evening.
By the way, is there any software that checks the integrity of ISO file? It took some 40 min. to download a ISO file.

Comment: i found something like in the link you can check it out. http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx116166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally installed it. What I had to do is: click stop installation (forget what it is exactly called), and installation took me to a try ubuntu environment. Played a little bit there with firefox and then I clicked install ubuntu from desktop. This time it was successful. It is very strange, but it fixed the problem, hope it hopes you. Thanks.